# Static variable and function issue

Tags: swift

The static variable always gives the same value. Why is not the function always called?

```
class SessionManager {
    static func AddSession(key : String, value : Any) {
        let session = UserDefaults.standard
        if session.object(forKey: key) != nil {
            session.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
        session.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value), forKey: key)        

    }

    static func GetSessionValue(key : String) -> Any? {
        let session = UserDefaults.standard
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: session.value(forKey: key) as! Data)
    }

    static var CurrentEmployee : Employee? = SessionManager.GetSessionValue(key: CL.SESSION__CURRENT_EMPLOYEE) as? Employee

}
```

`SessionManager.CurrentEmployee` always is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static var CurrentEmployee : Employee? = SessionManager.GetSessionValue(...) as? Employee
```

is a *stored* (type) property with an initial value which is evaluated
exactly *once,* when the property is accessed the first time.

What you want is a *computed* property, with a getter
which is evaluated on each access:

```
static var CurrentEmployee : Employee? { return SessionManager.GetSessionValue(...) as? Employee }
```

Self-contained example:

```
class Foo {

    static var currentNumber = 0

    static func nextNumber() -> Int {
        currentNumber += 1
        return currentNumber
    }

    static var storedProp = nextNumber()

    static var computedProp: Int { return nextNumber() }
}

print(Foo.storedProp) // 1
print(Foo.storedProp) // 1
print(Foo.storedProp) // 1

print(Foo.computedProp) // 2
print(Foo.computedProp) // 3
print(Foo.computedProp) // 4

print(Foo.storedProp) // 1
```